# Deep Link in iOS app does not go to Instagram

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, deep-linking

I've been trying to use deep linking in my iOS app. I've been testing it on an iPad Air running iOS 8.1, and the deep link works fine to open the twitter app, but is not able to open the Instagram app (and indeed, opens the twitter link instead...). Any ideas on why this might be happening? I've used the debugger to make sure the code is following the right paths, but I still can't work out what might be wrong. Could this be happening because the Instagram app is for iPhone instead of iPad?

```
@IBAction func illustratorButtonPressed() {
    var URL = ""
    var URLInApp = ""
    switch ApplicationConstants.illustratorContact.0 {
    case "twitter":
        URL = "http://twitter.com/" + ApplicationConstants.illustratorContact.1
        URLInApp = "twitter://user?screen_name=" + ApplicationConstants.illustratorContact.1
    case "instagram":
        URL = "http://instagram.com/" + ApplicationConstants.illustratorContact.1
        URLInApp = "instagram://user?username=" + ApplicationConstants.illustratorContact.1
    default:
        break
    }

    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(NSURL(string: URLInApp)!) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: URLInApp)!)
    } else {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: URL)!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to link from mobile Safari or the Notes app? Create a link and paste it in the Notes app and click on it to see if it opens Instagram. Alternatively if you have access to a web server, create a web page and place the links on it. Open the webpage with mobile safari and click on the links to see if Instagarm opens. I always use these tricks to test my own app and see how it behaves when triggers from an external url.

Comment: Juan, the deep links do work in the Notes app. I need a new hypothesis for why this isn't working...

Comment: Post more code, in particular how you define and assign values to `illustratorContact`